# Gnuplot plane curve

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plane and a line in the XYZ coordinate system. The line is crossing the plane at some point through my view angle. So that the line is on one point of the diagram below the plane and at some other points above the plane. However in my current perspective the line is always visible although it is below the plane and should be therefore not visible. Does any command exist how to make this way of displaying possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `hidden3d` option for hiding the respective line parts behind the surface:

```
set ticslevel 0
set hidden3d
set view 40,50
set isosamples 30
splot x+y, "-" with lines
10 10 -10
0 0 10
e
```

This gives (with 4.6.4):

[image]

For this solution you need a data file (or the inline data as specified above), to define your line. Don't know, if another variant is possible.

Also, what I noted is, that the surface grid is drawn above the line. I haven't found a way to change that. I'll investigate on that, maybe its a bug.